# capistrano 3 does not pass $USER to remote ssh

Tags: git, ssh, capistrano

In Capistrano 2, one could set the repo URL to include the login user name like:

```
set :repo_url, "git+ssh://#{ENV['LOGNAME']}@myrepo.example.com/path/name"
```

The purpose of doing this is that $LOGNAME accesses the repo using their
account, and gets their normal permissions.  The login on the deploy server is not ${LOGNAME}, which is fine.

While one can do this with capistrano 3, it works for the original user X, as they populate the ../repo/.git/config, but fails for the next user, since user Y can't login to myrepo.example.com as X.
This worked in Capistrano 2 because a fresh git repo was checked out each time.  The cap3 way is much more efficient, but I'm at a loss as to what to do.  If the /tmp/git-ssh-deploy-staging-user.sh script would add an -l user
to the ssh command line, all would be well, but I don't see anything to add that.

I've resorted to creating a "deploy" user on our repo server, and giving it read-only permissions to the repo, but I'm not terribly keen about this as a scalable solution, as it requires that $ADMIN screw with repo rather than let devops people do their thing.

I'm looking for suggestions?  Maybe it's just in the code, and I haven't found the option yet.

Answer (score 0):

With this patch to my deploy.rb I get a /tmp/ssh-blah-git.sh that has the -l option set correctly.

I was unable to override the existing one, because I think it hadn't loaded yet, and so I tried to run my task after the official one, but the official one ran a second time after my task (a total of three times...) so I clear it out.

```
namespace :git do
  desc "Upload the git wrapper script, this script guarantees that we can script git without getting an interactive prompt"
  task :better_wrapper do
    #puts "BETTER"
    on release_roles :all do
      execute :mkdir, "-p", File.dirname(fetch(:git_wrapper_path))
      upload! StringIO.new("#!/bin/sh -e\nexec /usr/bin/ssh -l #{ENV['LOGNAME']} -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \"$@\"\n"), fetch(:git_wrapper_path)
      execute :chmod, "700", fetch(:git_wrapper_path)
    end
    #puts "BETTER2"
    Rake::Task['git:wrapper'].clear_actions
  end

  after :wrapper, "git:better_wrapper"
end
```